# Evaluation with pre-trained model results in Type error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have a trained inceptionV3 model that I want to test on a new data set. However, i am getting TypeError concerning shape of image data. InceptionV3 model is a trained on 1500 image classification dataset.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


# dimensions of our images    -----   are these then grayscale (black and white)?
img_width, img_height = 139, 139

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('/home/DEV/model_inception.h5', compile=False)

# Get test image ready
test_image = cv2.imread('/home/images/0b53daf814304dd0d74efb2fa052ef23_0.png')
test_image = np.array(test_image)
test_image = cv2.resize(test_image,(img_width,img_height))
test_image = test_image.reshape(1,img_width, img_height,3) 
result = model.predict(test_image)
plt.imshow(result, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

The Type error that i am getting is

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 3, 3, 2048) for image data
```

How can I correct my evaluation model and and test it

Here is the sample of model summary

[model.summary](https://controlc.com/20961b8f)

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which line rise this error? And would you please attach your model summary? Or tell us the input and output shape of it?

Comment: Maybe it supports another shape different than your test image shape. You should check your **output shape before come to the dense layer** and **dense layer units**.

Comment: @Kaveh, I have edited my question and i have posted a link to my model summary , please review it.

Comment: Now it's clear. The output (``result``) is a (1,3,3,2048) tensor. And you want to plot it as image? What do you expect as output of your model? You have said it is a classification.

Comment: I think, you have used an Inception model with ``include_top=False``, but you have forgot to add your own dense classification layers at the end of model.

Comment: @Kaveh , i have added dense layers at the end of model , x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
#predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

Comment: But your model.summary() has not these layers at the end of model.

Comment: And what did you save? Better to update question and add your defined model code. Have you defined new model like this? ``new_model=Model(model.input,predictions)`` and save ``new_model.save(""somewhere)``?

Comment: And what did you save? Better to update question and add your defined model code. Have you defined new model like this? ``new_model=Model(model.input,predictions)`` and save ``new_model.save("model_inception.h5")``?

Comment: @Kaveh , I have upaded the question with my model summary https://controlc.com/20961b8f , the code for model is already posted in the previous question that you have answered.

Comment: @Kaveh , I have defined my model as final_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234084/discussion-between-devandev-and-kaveh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is for your input image to have shape(1,139,139,3)if this is what the image size was for the training images you used to train your model.
Next question is was your model trained on RGB or BGR images? cv2 reads in images as BGR. If your model was trained on RGB images then you need to convert the image from BGR to RGB with

```
image_rgb=cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Next question were the images your model was trained on have the pixel values scaled? Usually they are scale with

```
scaled_image=image/255
```

If the training images were scaled you need to scale the input image. Finally to get the image into the right shape use

```
image=np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
```

this adds the extra dimension needed by model.predict